# floating-ui react-dom-interactions how to set floating element width same as reference width

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, floating, popper.js, react-popper

In my react app I am trying to build a dropdown menu with `floating-ui/react-dom-interactions` (formerly knowns as `react-popper`). Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-haze-7pt4x2?file=/src/SecondaryCategoryItems.jsx) to a demo of my component. Here is a output of the current state of the app.

[image: Dropdown output]

I want to set the floating element width same as reference element. I have tried to follow [this approach](https://floating-ui.com/docs/size#match-reference-width) from documentation but didn't get the desired output. How can I set the floating element width same as reference element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the last solution with **size** key , as defined in the package

```
const { x, y, reference, floating, strategy, context } = useFloating({
    placement,
    open,
    middleware: [
      offset(4),
      size({
        apply({ rects, elements }) {
          Object.assign(elements.floating.style, {
            width: `${rects.reference.width}px`
          });
        }
      }),
      flip(),
      shift({ padding: 5 })
    ],
    onOpenChange: setOpen,
    whileElementsMounted: autoUpdate
  });
```

Check sandbox - **https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-marco-4yhuer?file=/src/SecondaryCategoryItems.jsx**

Comment: This is the one I wanted. I think missed the `elements` props. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have a grid the **grid-cols-4** for categories , it means each of one width is **25%** , I can suggest one solution without going deeper into package possibilities , Just add one class like

```
<div className={"bg-gray-700 py-2 text-white px-3 w-1/5 flex flex-col"}
  {...getFloatingProps({
  ref: floating,
  className: "Tooltip",
  style: {
    position: strategy,
    ref: floating,
    top: y ?? 0,
    left: x ?? 0,
  }
 })}
>
```

define styles in the index.css like

```
.Tooltip {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 90%;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: It would only work if the parent component has 100% width of browser window. But in my case the parent component is wrapped in a container. So declaring 25% width will give the floating element more width than reference element.

Comment: have you update your sandbox ? @AhashanAlamSojib

Comment: Yes. I have added some padding in the root component.

Answer (score 0):

One other solution with **paddings** , As I check in the main parent you have add **px-8** , it means , **2 em** from the start and end , you can pass grid and padding to the **SecondaryCategoryItems** component and calculate minWidth there like **minWidth: ("100" / grid ) - (p / 4) + "%"**

Sandbox example - https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-monad-vqm7ch?file=/src/SecondaryCategoryItems.jsx:1304-1340